# Wordpress Error - First argument is expected to be a valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress

The full error is
`call_user_func(myannouncer_addcheckbx) [function.call-user-func]:` First argument is expected to be a valid callback in `/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx/blog/wp-admin/includes/template.php` on line 927

Here is my code

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myannouncercheckboxes' );
function myannouncercheckboxes() {

    add_meta_box('annoncerid', 'WP Annoncer Post', 'myannouncer_addcheckbx', 'post');

}
```

// display the metabox

```
function myannouncer_addcheckbx($post) {
    echo 'Set This Post To Be Accessed By Wp Annoncer Customers <input type="checkbox" name="yesaddposttoannoncer" value="yes" /> <br />';
}
```

Please tell me why This is happening ...I even tried to remove $post in 
`function myannouncer_addcheckbx($post)` still get the error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't recognize the `myannouncer_addcheckbx` as a valid callback. Did you define it correctly in the right place?

Comment: Are you calling within a class? - If so, try array( $this, 'myannouncer_addcheckbx' ) as the callback parameter.

Comment: When you say the right place what do you mean.....I can be set up anywhere within the plugin as long as I use add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myannouncercheckboxes' ); the code and functions fall right after each other.... and the add_action only takes place on a post setup or edit...